# Cannot find index.html when it exists (Flask Python)

Tags: python, flask, server

In the near end of creating my server, I created a homepage and attached it to the python file, But when I tried to access the homepage from my phone, On the log it returned this:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /index.html
> - - [25/Dec/2021 20:27:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

index.html exists, This is a mysterious behaviour, Advice needed.

address.py:

```
api = Flask(__name__)

@api.route('/')
def index():
 return render_template('/index.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index.html` should be inside a directory called `templates`

Also you could do without the forward-slash in the argument to `render_template`:

```
  return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: This solved my problem as well, thank you @v25! If I may complement the answer by saying that there is another important folder for the flask project which is the folder called **static** folder. This one should contain the assets that will be used by the templates, like javascript, css and images.